# Values in Python list won't change in for loop

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, linear-algebra

I'm doing LU decomposition for a certain type of tridiagonal matrix and I'm having a problem with Python that I can't understand at all.

```
def trisolve2(b):
    length = len(b)

    # Solve Ly = b
    y = b.copy()
    for i in range(1, length):
        print('y[' + str(i) + '] = ' + str(b[i]) + ' - (-' + str(i) + ' / (' + str(i+1)
            + ')) * ' + str(y[i-1]))
        y[i] = b[i] - (-1 * i / (i+1)) * y[i-1]
    print("y = " + str(y))

    # Solve Ux = y
    x = y.copy()
    for i in range(length - 2, 0, -1):
        print("x = " + str(x))
        x[i] =  (y[i] + x[i+1]) / ((i+2) / (i+1))

    return x

test_b = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [0], [1]])
print("b = " + str(test_b))
test_x = trisolve2(test_b)
print("x = " + str(test_x))
```

I would expect when i = 1, for y[i] to be assigned to 1/2, and it even looks like it should with the print statements I put in there, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it never changes. y remains b, and x remains y without changing. The output is:

````
b = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
y[1] = [0] - (-1 / (2)) * [1]
y[2] = [0] - (-2 / (3)) * [0]
y[3] = [0] - (-3 / (4)) * [0]
y[4] = [1] - (-4 / (5)) * [0]
y = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
x = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
x = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
x = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
x = [[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]```
````

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with how multidimensional numpy arrays work rather than the mechanics of the for loop -- it smells a lot like a reference-vs-value problem.

Comment: Try using `deepcopy()` instead of `copy()`

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If Python 2.x (without `from __future__ import division`), then `i / (i+1)` _does not do what you may think_: it will always return zero. If that's the case, try including the _actual evaluated value_ of the expression `b[i] - (-1 * i / (i+1)) * y[i-1]` in your print statements to see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numpy array is defaulting to `int32`, 0.5 is getting rounded to the nearest integer: 1.

```py
>> b = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [0], [1]])
>> b
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]])
>> b.dtype
dtype('int32')
```

Try passing the [`dtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) argument:

```py
test_b = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [0], [1]], dtype=float)
```

Comment: Exactly. One way that the OP could've seen this is by printing _the actual evaluated value of the expression_ (`print( b[i] - (-1 * i / (i+1)) * y[i-1])`) rather than just printing it out with the variables replaced with their current values (`print('y[' + str(i) + '] = ' + str(b[i]) + ' - (-' + str(i) + ' / (' + str(i+1) + ')) * ' + str(y[i-1]))`)

Comment: Correct is to do type checking as often as possble when using numpy since vectorization code behind functions change often from c++ versions to linearized simd sequences. i've got similar problems since upgraded from python 3.5 to newer ones, and solved it doing some type checkings when passing float and double types to numpy. couldn't find the bug itself but overpassed the upgrade to newer python versions than 3.5. i found it worked nice in some 3.7.2 version but others had type passing bugs to numpy module